# run sub kernel in python kernel

Tags: python, ipython, zeromq, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I am trying to run the groovy kernel as a sub-kernel in python. I have added custom cell magic in python, so when user types `%%groovy` groovy kernel should be started using jupyter_client manager and execute code. currently, I am having a problem with sending a response. any help is appreciated.
here is my code so far:

```
from IPython.core.magic import (Magics, magics_class,cell_magic)
from jupyter_client import manager
from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel

@magics_class
class GroovyKernelMagic(Magics,Kernel):
    _execution_count = 1

    def run_cell(self, code):
        if not self.KernelManager.is_alive():
            Kernel.send_response(Kernel.iopub_socket, 'stream',
                               {'name': 'stdout', 'text': 'Restarting kernel "{}"\n'.format(self.KernelManager)})
            self.KernelManager.restart_kernel(now=False)
            self.KernelClient = self.KernelManager.client()
        while self.KernelClient.shell_channel.msg_ready():
            self.KernelClient.shell_channel.get_msg()
        self.KernelClient.execute(code, silent=False)

        _execution_state = "busy"
        while _execution_state != 'idle':
            while self.KernelClient.iopub_channel.msg_ready():
                sub_msg = self.KernelClient.iopub_channel.get_msg()
                msg_type = sub_msg['header']['msg_type']
                if msg_type == 'status':
                    _execution_state = sub_msg["content"]["execution_state"]
                else:
                    if msg_type in ('execute_input', 'execute_result'):
                        sub_msg['content']['execution_count'] = self._execution_count

                    Kernel.send_response(Kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type, sub_msg['content'])
        reply = self.KernelClient.get_shell_msg(timeout=10)
        reply['content']['execution_count'] = self._execution_count
        return reply['content']

    @cell_magic
    def groovy(self, line, cell):
        self.KernelManager, self.KernelClient = manager.start_new_kernel(startup_timeout=60, kernel_name='groovy')
        return self.run_cell(cell)


ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(GroovyKernelMagic)
```

this is the error stack trace:

/testMagic.py in groovy(self, line, cell)
     50     def groovy(self, line, cell):
     51         self.KM, self.KC = manager.start_new_kernel(startup_timeout=60, kernel_name='groovy')
---> 52         return self.run_cell(cell)
     53 
     54

/testMagic.py in run_cell(self, code)
     42                     print(msg_type)
     43                     print(sub_msg['content'])
---> 44                     Kernel.send_response(Kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type, sub_msg['content'])
     45         reply = self.KC.get_shell_msg(timeout=10)
     46         reply['content']['execution_count'] = self._execution_count

anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py in send_response(self, stream, msg_or_type, content, ident, buffers, track, header, metadata)
    343         message.
    344         """
--> 345         return self.session.send(stream, msg_or_type, content, self._parent_header,
    346                                  ident, buffers, track, header, metadata)
    347

AttributeError: 'Any' object has no attribute 'session'